# Disable smarty template_c (compile) folder

Tags: php, templates, smarty

Am new to smarty templates but have seen projects using smarty. I like the idea how it separates the codes from presentation and thought of learning.

Below is an example (crash course on smarty official website)

**index.php**

```
include('Smarty.class.php');

// create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

// assign some content. This would typically come from
// a database or other source, but we'll use static
// values for the purpose of this example.
$smarty->assign('name', 'george smith');
$smarty->assign('address', '45th & Harris');

// display it
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

**index.tpl**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Info</title>
</head>
<body>

<pre>
User Information:

Name: {$name}
Address: {$address}
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

and the **output**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Info</title>
</head>
<body>

<pre>
User Information:

Name: george smith
Address: 45th & Harris
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

works good.

What I notice after running the code above is that smarty compiles/creates a template_c folder.

How do I disable template_c folder?

Comment: Why do you need to disable it? It creates the folder for purpose. In fact, smarty is a **compiling** PHP template engine, and creation of this folder is one of the main aims of the library.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I have seen opencart having no template_c while it uses smarty ... just curious if it can be done?

Comment: This opencart https://github.com/opencart/opencart ? I doubt it uses smarty.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I thought it did, i saw tpl files in the view folders and thought so. You sure it aint smarty?

Comment: `tpl` stands for "template". It is not property of smarty, nor a unique extension which no one else uses. There are dozens of other template engines out there. PHP itself, to some degree, is a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable the compiling-directory. But may be it could be possible to point the compiling-directory to `/dev/null`.

```
$smarty->setCompileDir('/dev/null');
```

Have in mind, that your application needs to have rights for that folder. **Also have it mind, that it makes no sense to disable the compiling directory.**

see: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.compile.dir.tpl